# Google Geocoding API suddenly very slow

Tags: curl, google-geocoding-api

I was working on a site about a month ago that calls Google's geocoder and returned the results almost instantly.  Now when I attempt the call, it takes about 8 seconds.  Is anyone having problems with the service generally being slow?

I'm using php and curl to grab the information, for instance:

```
$url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1295 Federal Avenue, Los Angeles, CA&sensor=false";
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);    
$parsed = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
print_r($parsed);
```

Results are returning fine, just takes too long.  Also, if I use the same code to any other API provider, the results come back almost instantaneously again, which means the slowdown is not on my server's side.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

1) Obtain an [API key](https://code.google.com/apis/console/?noredirect) from Google.

2) Consider using [file_get_contents](http://php.net/file_get_contents) instead of cURL.

3) General hint: Use [urlencode](http://php.net/urlencode) for the address-variable.